# How i can use express-fileupload with fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send a file with fetch, but I need to get the file on the server side with the express-fileupload, is it possible?

My server side: 
here I am just getting the file with express-fileupload but I am sending through a form action, I need to get fetch but I do not know how to send the file through fetch so I can get it with req.files

```
async store(req, res) {
    var doce = req.body.doce;
    var nome = uniqid(doce+'-')+'.jpg';
    var caminho = `/img/${doce}/`;
    var tema = req.body.tema;
    let sampleFile = req.files.arquivo;
    sampleFile.mv(`./public${caminho}${nome}`, function(err){
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    });
    const candy = await Candy.create({
        nome: nome,
        doce: doce,
        caminho: caminho,
        tema: tema
    });

    return res.json(candy);
},
```

my fetch: 
here I tried to send by the body however on the server side using fileupload I can not recover the file using body, just files

```
let file = document.querySelector('input[name="arquivo"]').files[0] 

fetch('http://localhost:3000/candy', { method: 'post', headers: {'x-auth-token': window.sessionStorage.getItem('token'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify({
    doce: doce,
    tema: document.getElementById('docestipos').value,
    arquivo: file
})}).then...
```

Comment: async stuff on the Server is async on the Server. async activities on the Client are on the Client. I see a return value on the `async` on the Server?? `function async`, waits for a Promise to be resolved that you have `await` before, then the `await`, not the `async function`, returns the resolve arg of the Promise. Having return on `async function` is pointless. Also, on the Client you will want to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) instead of JSON.stringify on a file.

Comment: @PHPglue
Would I send this FormData in the body? But my doubt is really how to recover it using req.files and not req.body because with express-fileupload only req.files is allowed

Comment: Yes, just like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_a_file).

Comment: @PHPglue but I can not recover with req.body on the server side

Comment: `req.files.yourFormDataAppendName`